# Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core On .net core in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, f#, .net-core, aws-lambda

Using [this template,](https://github.com/lukemerrett/FSharp-Template-for-Aws-Lambda) I've been trying to get a Lambda function running. When it goes to execute a module containing

```
open Amazon
open Amazon.S3
```

it blows up with a

> "errorType": "FileNotFoundException",
>
> "errorMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'. The system cannot find the file specified.",`

I've tried a `nuget install` of AWSSDK.Core to no avail.

```
Errors in /Users/sanitized/aws_lambda/project.json
    Package AWSSDK.Core 3.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package AWSSDK.Core 3.1.0 supports:
      - monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
      - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
      - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
      - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
      - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
      - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
      - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Here's the dependencies section of my project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-*",
    "Amazon.Core": "0.6.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0*",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1"
    }
  },
```

The Lambda libraries seem to load correctly, but attempting to use an S3 client breaks. What're the .net-core blessed equivalents of AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states:

> Package AWSSDK.Core 3.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)

According to [this link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/318):

> ```
> To use the the AWS sdk in ASP.NET Core based applications you 
> need to use the 3.2.X versions of the NuGet packages. 
> Note, they are currently marked as beta.
> ```

Comment: `"AWSSDK.Core": "3.3.5", "AWSSDK.S3": "3.3.5"` did the trick.